# disadvantages for having a class with many fields

Tags: java, collections

I have a class that has many fields made of objects of other classes. This class is used by multiple people who keep adding more fields to it according to their needs. I want to know if there's a drawback to this compared to having one collection field, say a Hashmap, in this class which can be used to contain other classes as and when necessary. This looks cleaner to me than declaring many fields which might end up not being used

Comment: The disadvantage of using a map is that you will bind the parameter object to a string value (or any other). Thus, if you make a mistake somewhere in writing a key for parameter in the code, you will not recognize it at the compilation stage, only on runtime. You will also have to use a Map<String, Object> if the fields are of different types. Therefore, you have to do cast to use them, and this may be the cause for ClassCastException.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could provide a sample piece of your code, it will help anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: “…is used by multiple people who keep adding more fields to it according to their needs” sounds like a fundamental problem in your development process which renders the problems of the resulting code negligible.

Comment: I get the type-safety disadvantages of using the map as against declaring fields in this class. My question really is geared towards performance drawbacks. Is there any performance hit with defining a class with say 200 fields against a class that has only one field defined that can take an anonymous collection?

Answer (score 1):

A class with too many fields and methods is certainly harder to grasp and change later on - the shorter the class is, the easier it is to understand its uses.

On the other hand, keeping different class variables inside one hashmap in order to make the class shorter is not a good idea at all because you will lose type safety and will have to add many additional checks and castings later on.

In conclusion you should always keep the classes as simple and clean as possible without sacrificing best coding practices - perhaps instead of having so many different fields in one class you could have multiple smaller classes, each with their own responsibility, instead.